# How do i get request and response count in scrapyd?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, scrapyd, portia

I am trying to get request and response count in scrapyd,while running multiple spider means 8 spider dynamically.I am try to get those count using python.

following counts:

```
enter code here{'downloader/request_bytes': 130427,
 'downloader/request_count': 273,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 273,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 2169984,
 'downloader/response_count': 273,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 271,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 2,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 416,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 21, 14, 21, 38, 13000),
 'item_scraped_count': 119,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 406,
 'log_count/INFO': 44,
 'offsite/domains': 9,
 'offsite/filtered': 5865,
 'request_depth_max': 14,
 'response_received_count': 273,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 273,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 273,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 273,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 273,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 21, 14, 16, 41, 144000)}
enter code here
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Stats Collection](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html) from Scrapy.

With this you can access the statistics dumped at the end to the console and if you write your own middleware you can combine the results of your 8 spiders together -- like in the example of the documentation.

Comment: is there any sample scripting in python level.